# Stripping Comments out of a file in PHP

Tags: php

I have to parse various files that contain comments of differing types.  I have been trying to figure an easy way to strip out these comments, but nothing good so far.  I have full line comments that start with both # and ; and comments that start after relevant data.  Best example:

```
data
data
#comment
;comment
data ;comment
data #comment
```

Any help in stripping these comments?  And perhaps blank lines as well?

Answer (score 4):

This should work ([live demo](http://codepad.org/gKRJ7mET)):

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/
        [;#]    # remove strings starting with ; or #
        .*      # and everything following that
        $       # until it ends in a newline
    /mx',       // make it span multilines
    '',
    $data
);
```

The above will leave blanks lines where full line comments have been. If you want to replace those as well, add `\s` before the first `[;#]` (as shown by @konforce below).

Answer (score 3):

```
$t = ltrim(preg_replace('/\s*[#;].*$/m', '', $t));
```

Should work. Removes all comments, making sure not to leave any blank lines where comments used to be. Also kills whitespace before comments, but that can be changed (`\s` to `\n`) if you don't want that.

Edit: Just saw the note regarding removing blank lines. The following should remove both comments and blank lines:

```
$t = ltrim(preg_replace('/(\s*[#;].*$)|(^\s*)/m', '', $t));
```

Untested, but the second condition should catch blank (only whitespace) lines. The `ltrim` is still necessary to remove any whitespace that a leading comment may have caused. Possibly could catch that as part of the regexp, but I think it's less complex with an `ltrim`.

Edit Again: Actually the above would remove all leading whitespace on each line. If that's a problem, you could fix it with:

```
$t = ltrim(preg_replace('/(\s*[#;].*$)|(^\s*\n)/m', '', $t));
```

Comment: +1 works and is better than mine. could use /x though for some inline documentation so you still understand it when reading it in three months.

Comment: @Gordon, that's good suggestion, but I won't be using this code in three months and it's a good exercise for the reader to add the comments himself. ;) (Truthfully, I'm just lazy.)

Comment: thanks for the help.  I'm using the last code snippit in my code.  Thank you again.